# passing a filename with a space in the name in a get request

Tags: java, filenames, get-request

I have two copies of a file. One is CatBoarding.mp4 and the other is Cat Boarding.mp4

When I execute:`http://localhost:8080/VT/Pages/jspDynamic/dynamic.jsp?video=CatBoarding.mp4` in chrome in works fine.

However when I try:

1. `http://localhost:8080/VT/Pages/jspDynamic/dynamic.jsp?video="Cat Boarding.mp4"`
2. `http://localhost:8080/VT/Pages/jspDynamic/dynamic.jsp?video='Cat Boarding.mp4'`
3. `http://localhost:8080/VT/Pages/jspDynamic/dynamic.jsp?video=Cat Boarding.mp4`
4. `http://localhost:8080/VT/Pages/jspDynamic/dynamic.jsp?video=Cat%20Boarding.mp4`

The file is not found.  I do notice that the browser inserts a %20 for the space in each case

@the_storyteller discovered the problem was not with how I was passing the parameter to the jsp but rather with how I was using the parameter inside the jsp.  Originally we had inside the jsp file:

```
<source src= <%= "../../videos/" + video %> type='video/mp4'>
```

this ends up looking like:

```
<source src= videos/Cat Boarding.mp4 type='video/mp4'>
```

There are two easy ways to fix:

1. add `video = video.replace(" ","%20");` in the jsp file
2. or change

   `<source src= <%= "'../../videos/" + video + "'" %> type='video/mp4'>`

Comment: URL's can't have spaces, so they are replaced with %20, which is the character code for that character.

Comment: great. but the space is in a parameter as part of a get request.  Are you saying filenames can't have spaces in them?

Comment: They can have spaces - `%20` is an encoded space. The url will be sent with the space, and the server (in this case the web browser in your laptop) will decode the parameter and turn the `%20` back into a space.
See this document explaining the encoding. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused by your responses.  Can I pass a filename with a space in it or not? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes. Replace the space (the `' '`) with `%20`. It will be turned back into a space by the server.

So the file with the name `this is a file.txt` would be `this%20is%20a%20file.txt` when url encoded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190459/discussion-between-the-storyteller-and-dcr).

Comment: @the_storyteller, your final insight was spot on!  Thank you. When I added video = video.replace(" ","%20");   before  <source src= <%= "../../videos/" + video %> type='video/mp4'> it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Can you edit your post to include the code snippet, and an advanced problem description, so as to assist others in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i don't understand why you tagged this questions as a java question, hope this will help:

Remember that "space" in URL/URN is seen as an unsafe characters. [RFC1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630) says:

```
  There is a conflict between the need to be able to represent many
  characters including spaces within a URI directly, and the need to
  be able to use a URI in environments which have limited character
  sets or in which certain characters are prone to corruption.  This
  conflict has been resolved by use of an hexadecimal escaping
  method which may be applied to any characters forbidden in a given
  context.  When URLs are moved between contexts, the set of
  characters escaped may be enlarged or reduced unambiguously.

  The use of white space characters is risky in URIs to be printed
  or sent by electronic mail, and the use of multiple white space
  characters is very risky.  This is because of the frequent
  introduction of extraneous white space when lines are wrapped by
  systems such as mail, or sheer necessity of narrow column width,
  and because of the inter-conversion of various forms of white
  space which occurs during character code conversion and the
  transfer of text between applications.  This is why the canonical
  form for URIs has all white spaces encoded.
```

So i supposed that if you need use a "risky" or "ambiguous" URI in your code, just replace risky characters by their percent-encoding code (%20 for space, %3C for "<", etc.)

Another way to solve this, is to save in your case, your video files with a more safely name called "slug" more easily readable by both users and system (like search engine or http client).

For example french title use character that may cause the same issue (é, è, î, à, ç, etc.). With slug you can change in your files before saving it to your server, all "space" occurences with the character of your choice (for example "-" or "_").

Slugify (com.github.slugify) in java can help you to do this